# Generate sequence no for row avoiding duplicate row in crystal report XI

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

[image]

code i have used

```
whileprintingrecords; numbervar var; var := var+1; var
```

also i have used the supress if duplicate

I want to avoid count if duplicate as shown in image file
1922
1923
1924
1925
1926
but 1923 and 1924 are duplicate row so i want to avoid count 1924 display sno like
1922
1923
1924
1925

Answer (score 0):

Apply the same condition used to suppress to the logic of when the variable is NOT incremented.

So instead of var := var+1; you would have something like:

```
IF (NOT Suppress_Condition) Then var := var+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

whileprintingrecords; 
numbervar var; 
if (({USP_ExCombWeaponAmmunitionList;1.RegistrationNo}) = previous({USP_ExCombWeaponAmmunitionList;1.RegistrationNo}))
then
var := var 
else
var := var+1;

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

enter code here
    whileprintingrecords; 
    Global  numbervar var; 
    if OnFirstRecord then
        var := 1
    else if (({USP_Get_CVR_Project_Type_List;1.ProjectID}) = 
       previous({USP_Get_CVR_Project_Type_List;1.ProjectID})) then
        var
    else
        var := var+1;